# Include only field in Django model.

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django read-only model, it has one column with geojson data, this field can easily be 500mb.

Most of the times I don't have to work with this field, so I would like it to exclude from standard select queries. Is there some way to exclude it? I know I can exclude it with `values_list` but I am more interested in default behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## At queryset level

You can use [**`.defer('field1', 'field2')`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#defer) to prevent Django from fetching certain fields *immediately*. In that case they can later be fetched with an extra query.

So you can write your queries like:

```
SomeModel.objects.all().defer('geo_field')
```

to exclude that from the fetch. The queryset then contains `SomeModel` objects, so not a list of values. Behaviour you have defined on `SomeModel` (for example a utility method) can be used. Furthermore you still *can* use the `some_model_object.geo_field`, but then it will require an extra fetch before you can access the corresponding value.

It is however advisable to *only* use such tricks in case the processing of certain columns is very significant. After all, such extra queries take time as well. If you often need such field, it will typically only result in more expensive processing.

## Constructing a custom `Manager`

The above is of course not very elegant: now we have to write `.defer(..)` for every query. We can however design a manager that defers automatically when we access `SomeModel.objects`:

```
from django.db import models

class GeoManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().defer('geo_field')
```

Then in `SomeModel`, we can use this manager for `objects` instead of the default one:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    geo_field = ...

    objects = GeoManager()
    with_geofield = models.Manager()
```

Here you will thus by default not fetch the `geo_field` if you access `SomeModel.objects`, and if you know you need it, you can use `SomeModel.with_geofield` to immediately fetch the `geo_field` as well.